# SQL pivot output result set of a COUNT in MySQL without UNION nor GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot

I'm working on couple of millions of lines so I won't use an UNION to display my query as I would like.
For design purposes I need this query returned in a certain way to upload automatically a pie chart.

Query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(IF( b IS NULL, id , NULL)) AS 'not_assigned',
    COUNT(IF(b IS NOT NULL, id, NULL)) AS 'assigned'
FROM table
WHERE 
    OverType = "abc"
    AND Type = "def"
    AND Sub_Type = "ghi"
    AND Date BETWEEN "2022-12-01" AND "2022-12-25"
    AND Client LIKE '%john%';
```

Result set:

```
not_assigned    assigned
1000            500
```

So I would like to transform the output as this:

```
                Count
not_assigned    1000
assigned        500
```

Any advice for a MySQL version 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may aggregate by a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 'not_assigned' ELSE 'assigned' END AS category,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE 
    OverType = 'abc' AND
    Type = 'def'
    Sub_Type = 'ghi' AND
    Date BETWEEN '2022-12-01' AND '2022-12-25' AND
    Client LIKE '%john%'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! And what about another condition as `COUNT(IF((b IS NOT NULL AND a IS NOT NULL), id, NULL)) AS 'known', COUNT(IF((b IS NOT NULL AND a IS NULL), id, NULL)) AS 'not_known'`?

Comment: Use: `CASE WHEN b IS NOT NULL AND a IS NOT NULL THEN 'known' ELSE 'not_known' END` and also aggregate by this.

Comment: Finally I went with this: `CASE 
 WHEN (b IS NOT NULL AND a IS NOT NULL) THEN 'known'
 WHEN (b IS NOT NULL AND a IS NULL) THEN 'half_known'
 ELSE 'not_known' END AS category,`